# Is this the proper use of an array and isset?

Tags: php, forms, validation, post, submit

So I've got this code and part of it is a form, and ALL fields are absolutely required.

I just can't find clear documentation for my needs to validate everything.

would I do something like this?

```
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
$bar = $_POST['bar'];
$lorem = $_POST['lorem'];
$ipsum = $_POST['ipsum'];

$isSet = array($foo, $bar, $lorem, $ipsum);

if(isset($isSet)) { /* Do the stuff */ }
```

or is there a better way? I don't really want to do

```
if(isset($foo) && isset($bar) && isset($lorem)........
```

because i've got about 12 fields that are required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
if (isset($foo, $bar, $lorem, $ipsum)) {.....}
```

Saves you one step.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Perfect! I'm not sure why I couldn't think of that :/

Answer (score 2):

Remember that isset will return true if you have an empty string.  So, technically

```
isset($_POST['foo'])
```

would return true if foo is passed in with a blank value:

```
foo=&bar=&...etc.
```

Also,

```
isset(array())
```

returns true;

If "" is not a valid value for one of those variables, you will want to do the following:

```
$requiredFields = array('foo', 'bar', 'lorem', 'ipsum');

$allValid = true;

foreach ($requireFields => $fieldName) {
    if (isset($_POST[$fieldName]) && $_POST[$fieldName] != "") {
        $allValid = $allValid && true;
    } else {
        $allValid = $allValid && false;
    }
}

if ($allValid) {
    //...success...
} else {
    //...failed...
}
```

You essentially check that the variable was passed and also that the variable is not set to "".

Hope that helps.